# Compiled private key

Tags: security, compilation, cryptography

Is it safe to distribute a compiled program (C, say - definitely not Java) with a cryptographic private key, in the sense of the key being deducible from the executable? What if multiple executables differ only in that, in the source, different private keys are used?

I remember reading some time back that antiviruses could recognize suspicious patterns in binary executables, and from assembly it seems like it'd be possible to deduce the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you create a scheme for hiding data from your own user, ask yourself this question: Could this scheme be used to prevent unauthorized software copies (i.e. could this stop "piracy?") If the answer is yes, then ask yourself this question: Do unauthorized software copies exist? If the answer to both is yes, then your scheme almost certainly does not work.

You cannot both give someone data and hide it from them. If your program, running on your user's computer, can access the secret, the user can also access the secret. You can obfuscate it, but if they can run a debugger, they can always just pull the key out of your program after your program unscrambles it.

The end lesson of this is that you can authorize users (because they store their passwords in their brains). You cannot authorize programs or general-purpose devices (and you can barely authorize specialized devices, other than to demonstrate that the user possesses it).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe. A private key is supposed to be kept private

Comment: Correct. You cannot keep secrets in an executable or other distributed file.

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell if it is safe or not safe, we need to know what the private key is being used for.  Depending on the use case for this private key, it could indeed be safe.